Google App Engine Takes way too long to deploy simple app (20 - 40 minutes)
I am deploying a pretty simple NodeJS express backend but deployments take 20 - 40 minutes each time, I even try to specify the previously deployed image but it doesnt really make any difference. is there anything that can be done to speed it up ?
My plan is to have Google App Engines running the same project in 3 geo locations behind a serverless neg, but i am worried that if i need to push a change it wont propagate in a timely manner at all.
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: api

runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
  runtime_version: "18"

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
  
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto  
    
network:
  session_affinity: true        

